# Passing 3D dynamic array by reference

Tags: c++, memory, dynamic, multidimensional-array, pass-by-reference

I'm trying to create a 3D char array with dynamic memory.  I create the char*** point in main then pass it to input and everything works fine until the input function returns and i try to repring the same locaton from main.  I get "Access violation reading location."  Any suggestions?

```
void input(char ***a, int f, int n)
{
cin >> f;
cin >> n;
a = new char**[f];

for (int i =0; i <f; ++i)
{
    a[i]= new char*[n];

    for (int j=0; j <n; ++j)
    {
        a[i][j] = new char[n];
    }
}

for (int i =0; i<f; ++i)
{
    for (int j=0; j<n; ++j)
    { 
       for (int k = 0; k <n ;++k)
       {
          a[i][j][k] = '.';
          cout << a[i][j][k];}
       }
    }

    cout <<endl << endl<< a[2][5][5]; //test to see is value is '."
}

int main()
{
    char ***station = 0;
    int floors=0, n=0;
    input(station, floors, n);
    cout << endl << endl << station[2][5][5];
}
```

Comment: `char ***&a` might do what you want.

Comment: tried that, doesn't work.

Comment: [See it live](http://ideone.com/CsJ59Z).